# Wildcard routes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to have a wildcard route? But only with specific names.

Eg.

I have a number of routes that lead to the same place:

```
/archive/gallery/1/picture/1
/masters/gallery/1/picture/1
/browse/gallery/1/picture/1
```

These all load up the same picture, but it would be great if I could do something like this:

```
Route::get('{???}/gallery/{galleryId}/picture/{pictureId}', array(
    'as'=>'picture',
    'uses'=>'PictureController@getPicture'
));
```

But only use archive or masters or browse as the wildcard.

Comment: So you have three resources, but you want to make router generic with wildcards ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a different controller, depending on the wildcard. You would have to define that in the controller.

```
Route::get('{page}/gallery/{galleryId}/picture/{pictureId}', array(
    'as'=>'picture',
    'uses'=>'PictureController@getPicture'
));

public function getPicture($page)
{
   if ($page == "archive")
        return View::make('archive');
   else if ($page == "browse")
        return View::make('browse');
   else if ($page == "masters")
        return View::make('masters');
}
```

be sure to place the route at the bottom of the routes file though, otherwise it will override the other routes  :) as laravel uses first-in -> first->out

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
Route::get('{type}/gallery/{galleryId}/picture/{pictureId}', array(
    'as'=>'picture',
    'uses'=>'PictureController@getPicture'
))->where('type', 'masters|browse|archive');
```

PictureController:

```
public function getPicture($type, $galleryId, $pictureId)
{
    // $type could be only masters or browse or archive
    // otherwise requested route won't match

    // If you want to load view depending on type (using type)
    return View::make($type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have your `{???}` this can simply be a regular expression.

Maybe something like this `{(archive|browse|masters)}`

Update: I think the above works in L3, but L4 has to be done differently

```
Route::get('/{variable}', function()
{
    return View::make('view');
})->where('masters', 'browse', 'archive');
```